# How is voltage induced in Yd transformer without neutral connection sinusoidal?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, power-engineering, harmonics

Thia is regarding bank of 3 single-phase transformers having star connected primary with isolated neutral and delta connected secondary.

I know that for bank of 3 single phase transformer core flux and hence voltage induced will be sinusoidal only if 3rd harmonic currents (which are *cophasal* - i.e. 3rd harmonics of all 3 phase will be in phase with each other) can flow, otherwise owing to saturation flux will be flat-topped and induced emf peaky.

But all sources I refer (I'll cite them if necessary) says that Yd transformer without neutral will have sinusoidal emf induced in them. I don't understand how, because third harmonic currents can circulate inside closed delta winding but won't it require balancing amp-turns in primary? If so, then wouldn't those balancing amp-turn require cophasal currents in primary which is not allowed as there's no neutral?

Is my thinking that cophasal currents inside closed detla will require cophasal currents in star right?

Comment: Hi Deep - It will take you a while, but i believe a thorough read of [The Whys of the Wyes](http://apps.geindustrial.com/publibrary/checkout/GET-3388B?TNR=White%20Papers|GET-3388B|generic) will help you.

Comment: @relayman357 Oh thanks man! I've given it brief look and it looks so promising! I shall check it as soon as I get time enough to justify it! Thnx a ton 